# Object and array iteration in react and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one array and one object with the same name say **checkArr** and it would be like `checkArr = []` and `checkArr= {}`

And contents of the both array and object attached here .
I have already written the loop for  Array name checkArr like.

```
let checkArrIte = checkArr.map((checkArrItem, i) => { 
  and here the iterating code some 50 lines of code.
}
```

But if the checkArr = {} then how it will compare here and give it into the 
else condition .Here the object body also contains the same code as checkArr

My only requirement is when the object is comes like `checkObj = {}` then it 
will take only the object and body would be same as array.

checkArr:

[image]

checkObj

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/amitpowerpeace/oLw6e4ua/18/

See in this fiddle there are two things 
one if I checked using Array.IsArray and other one using typeof

How can we combine both into the one funcutin?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You can iterate over an object using for...in or loop over Object.keys - many ways to skin a cat

Comment: Just add a simple converter yourself: `checkObj = Array.isArray(checkObj) ? checkObj : [checkObj];`. Now you can just assume that `checkObj` will always be an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the condition:

```
let checkArrIte
if(checkArr.constructor.name === 'Array') {
  checkArrIte = checkArr.map((checkArrItem, i) => { 
    //...
  }
} else if(checkArr.constructor.name === 'Object') {
  checkArrIte = Object.keys(checkArr).map((checkArrItem, i) => { 
    //...
  }
} else {
  //...
}
```